# live validation javascript not running in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, validation, live

I am trying to use a pre-built javascript library called LiveValidation, that validates a test field as you type in it. The script is running fine in FireFox, but it's not working in IE at all. I went to the website of LiveValidation where it says that it supports IE 6,7,8 (i am using IE7), and I have confirmed that Javascript is enabled.

This is the link to the Javascript files...
http://livevalidation.com/download

And this is the HTML code where I use the validator...

```
           <label>First Name<font style="color:#FF0000;">*</font> </label>
            <input type="text" value="" name="first_name" id="first_name"/>
            <script type="text/javascript">
            var f1 = new LiveValidation('first_name');
            f1.add(Validate.Presence,{failureMessage: " Please enter username"});
            f1.add(Validate.Format,{pattern: /^[a-z\s]+$/i ,failureMessage: " It allows only characters"});
            f1.add(Validate.Format,{pattern: /^[a-zA-Z][a-z\s]{0,}$/,failureMessage: " Invalid username"});
            f1.add(Validate.Length, { minimum: 4, maximum: 15 } );
            </script>
```

Comment: If your question has been answered, or if it is no longer valid, please 'tick' to choose the most appropriate answer so everyone knows that the problem has been resolved. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably enclose your validation code in a function, and then call that function whenever the user types into the textfield. For example...

```
       <script type="text/javascript">
        function doValidation(){
            var f1 = new LiveValidation('first_name');
            f1.add(Validate.Presence,{failureMessage: " Please enter username"});
            f1.add(Validate.Format,{pattern: /^[a-z\s]+$/i ,failureMessage: " It allows only characters"});
            f1.add(Validate.Format,{pattern: /^[a-zA-Z][a-z\s]{0,}$/,failureMessage: " Invalid username"});
            f1.add(Validate.Length, { minimum: 4, maximum: 15 } );
            }
        </script>

        <label>First Name<font style="color:#FF0000;">*</font> </label>
        <input type="text" value="" name="first_name" id="first_name" onKeyPress="doValidation()" />
```

So, every time the user presses a key in the textfield, it will call the `doValidation()` and run the `LiveValidator`. I think that IE is doing the correct thing, and Firefox might just be helping you out by guessing what you were intending to code.